# make serialized form POST to php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

my problem is that I'm sending html form data via jquery here's the code :

```
 $('#search_button').click(function(event) {                                    
    var track_load = 0; //total loaded record group(s)
    var loading  = false; //to prevents multipal ajax loads
    var total_groups = <?php echo $total_groups; ?>; //total record group(s)

    var Data = $("#srch_form").serializeArray();
    console.log(Data);

    $('#results').load("autoload_process.php", {
        data:Data, 
      'group_no':track_load},
 function() {track_load++;}); //load first group
});
```

and in the php receiving page I'm getting an array with one array per name&value pair inside like this :

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'srch_word' (length=9)
      'value' => string '' (length=0)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'srch_cat-2' (length=10)
      'value' => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'srch_cat-5' (length=10)
      'value' => string '5' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'srch_cat-6' (length=10)
      'value' => string '6' (length=1)
```

But before with html only form post I was getting one array with the pairs inside :

```
array (size=4)
  'srch_word' => string '' (length=0)
  'srch_cat-2' => string '2' (length=1)
  'srch_cat-5' => string '5' (length=1)
  'srch_cat-6' => string '6' (length=1)
```

And I use to access the values like an associative array would do `($_POST['srch_word']`, or even just `$srch_word would work )`, now I can't do that.

¿How can I get one array from the jquery post or how can I reduce this array of arrays to one array in the php file or what should I do in this case? 
I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is sample maybe usefull for you as long number of child array always two

```html
<?php
$keys = array();
$value = array();
$serialize = array(array('name' => 'srch_word', 'value' => ''), array('name' => 'srch_cat-2', 'value' => '2'));
foreach ($serialize as $key) {
  array_push($keys, $key['name']);
  array_push($value, $key['value']);
}
$final = array_combine($keys, $value);
echo '<pre>',print_r($final),'</pre>';
?>
```

replace $serialize as your array define
please vote if you like it

Comment: can i see your input array or maybe input form and how you define your post? it shouldbe create array as you want.

Comment: im creating the post when click on div#clas_search_button, not the form input button

Comment: can you give me **getSticky** function and **getCat()** ?

Comment: last one.. can you give me your php code for insert this post variable

Comment: Well thats all I think. If you need something else just let me know and many thanks for the help so far.

Comment: console.log will much help when you serialize ajax post, you could post here..just to make sure how you post your serialize array

Comment: ok, the result of the console log is at the end of the cuestion.(in the browser is more 'presented' not in one line)

Comment: @Cactux what I mean is how you handle serialize post with ajax in server side.?

Comment: answer is edited, please adapt to your code and explain what is your expected result?

Comment: This was really helpful thank you @ntaloventi (I Couldn't vote you up because I'm a beginner sorry)

Comment: it's fine.. nice to help you..(I'm also beginner reputation is what I'm expecting)